# List.Contains not working as expected with custom struct argument

Tags: c#, struct, collections, value-type

I have a struct IntVector2 which has an X and Y property. The + operator is overridden with

```
public static IntVector2 operator +(IntVector2 value1, IntVector2 value2)
{
    value1.X += value2.X;
    value1.Y += value2.Y;
    return value1;
}
```

When using this in a List with the contains method, it's not checking the total value of the addition, but just the variable "current"

```
if (visited.Contains(current + dir))
    continue;
```

What's actually going on here?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the values of the variables, and a variable declaration that equals what I'm expecting the value of the contains to check.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30062610/Brokestuff.png

Edit2: Here's the full code of the method, it's the start of an A* Pathfinding algorithm finding the end vector from the start vector.

```
                    public Path Pathfind(IntVector2 start, IntVector2 end)
    {
        Queue<IntVector2> fillQueue = new Queue<IntVector2>();
        List<IntVector2> visited = new List<IntVector2>();
        fillQueue.Enqueue(start);
        IntVector2 current;
        while (fillQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            current = fillQueue.Dequeue();
            foreach (IntVector2 dir in Directions)
            {
                if (GetCell(current + dir).IsWall)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    IntVector2 newstuff = current + dir;
                    if (visited.Contains(current + dir))
                        continue;
                    if ((current + dir) == end)
                    {
                        //We've reached the target, traceback the path and return it.
                    }
                    visited.Add(current);
                    fillQueue.Enqueue(current + dir);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Edit 3: Even using the newstuff variable which has a different value from the start hits the continue. I'm not sure what it could be doing. My equals override just checks if X and Y are both equal and returns true if so.

Here's the entirety of the IntVector2 code: http://pastebin.com/ic108SeF

Edit 4: I modified the + operator to:

```
        public static IntVector2 operator +(IntVector2 value1, IntVector2 value2)
    {
        return new IntVector2((value1.X + value2.X), (value1.Y + value2.Y));
    }
```

And the problem still persists.

Comment: why are you modifying `value1`?

Comment: Have you changed your `Equals` definition? `((1,1) + (2,2)).Equals(3,3)` yields `true` for me.

Comment: I figured modifying the first argument with the value of the second would work. Should I change it to return a new IntVector2 with the new total instead of modifying the first?

Comment: I have overriden equals with    
    
    public bool Equals(IntVector2 other)
        {
            return (X == other.X) && (Y == other.Y);
        }

Comment: @user3010006 Then put a breakpoint there and debug it - because it definitely does work for the default `Equals` implementation. Also, please show us the values of `currentDir`, `dir` and what you expect to be in `visited`.

Comment: In my example of it not working, visited has one entry X:13, Y:7, current is X13, Y:7 and dir is X:1, Y:0 which would add into X:14, Y:7 which is not in visited, but still continues.

Comment: You need to override the equals operator too.

Comment: @Ryios it is overriden, I posted the code for it in the 4th comment but I'm not sure how to format the code in the comment :/

Comment: @user3010006 Something else is going on. The code definitely works, assuming we've seen it all. I would imagine what's actually in visited is not what you expect. https://dotnetfiddle.net/PYLnzO

Comment: Here's a terrible screenshot of the current breakpoint highlighting the variables values:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30062610/Brokestuff.png

Comment: @user3010006 Can you please check the fiddle I provided? Please show us the full code of how you're populating the list and comparing it

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NqatNd for the fixed fiddle

Comment: Ok, don't modify Value1 and Value2 passed into operator overloads.  Those same instances could be in the collection you are calling contains on, and when you do that you mess up the collection because contains is relying on the values of x.y on those instances.  In your operator overloads, create a new instance of IntVector2 for the result of the addition without modifying the originals and return that.

Comment: @Ryios I updated the + operator to return a new Vector2 with the total value and it's still giving the same problem. :/

Comment: Can you add all the code for IntVector2?

Comment: I posted a pastebin of it in my edit, http://pastebin.com/ic108SeF

note that the new +operator returns a new vector 
"return new IntVector2((value1.X + value2.X), (value1.Y + value2.Y));"

Also, I'm new to the SO convention, should I just post the code in the OP, or use pastebin? I figured 150 lines was a bit much for the main post.

Comment: man, I'm blind so sorry, looking at it now  But yeah typically people always post the code.  The past bin link could go down, then the question becomes broken for people in the future.

Comment: No worries! I appreciate all the help, I'm actually just stumped. Seems like no matter what the value is, it's always kicking through to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the `Equals` method:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{ 
    if (obj is IntVector2)
    {
        return Equals((IntVector2)this); // <-- "this" should be "obj"
    }
}
```

The erroneous code compares `this` to `this`, so it always returns `true`.

Comment: Think I got it, trying now. Thanks!

Comment: Also you have contains instead of equals for the method name. But I got it :3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I believe I figured out your problem.

Your equals override isn't an override, you have it in your code as:

```
    public bool Equals(IntVector2 other) { 
        return (X == other.X) && (Y == other.Y); 
    }
```

What you did there was added a Method called Equals.  So you have in effect overloaded the Actual equals method you need to override.  Contains won't call your equals method, because it calls the original one that takes an object.

And when you override the right equals method you should, in good practice, implement GetHashCode and use GetHashCode to determine if the objects are truly equal.

In your case you won't have an issue not overriding GetHashCode, as you are basing eqaulity on two integers being the same in another copy of the IntVector2, and you can't really compute an integer hash code for that as X and Y are both integers.  If you did a GetHashCode implementation here, you could run into bugs later if you have a large number of these you could end up with dupe hash codes that are non equal objects.

Here is the updated code you should try.

```
public struct IntVector2
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public static IntVector2 operator +(IntVector2 value1, IntVector2 value2)
    {
        value1.X += value2.X;
        value1.Y += value2.Y;
        return value1;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //overrode this to get rid of warning
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    //This equals get's called, notice the override keyword
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is IntVector2)
        {
            IntVector2 vObj = (IntVector2)obj;
            return vObj.X == this.X && vObj.Y == this.Y;           
        }
        return false;
    }

    //This won't get called, it's not part of the framework, this is adding a new overload for equals that .Net won't know about.
    public bool Equals(IntVector2 other)
    {
        return (X == other.X) && (Y == other.Y);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{ value1: {0}, value2: {0} }", X, Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I was going off the wrong pastebin link, I was looking at the other one, but this typo was in there too.

Comment: Thanks Ryios. I wish I could mark you both correct! My accounts too noob to upvote too. :( Good catch on that though!

Comment: @user3010006: You should implement the `IEquatable<IntVector2>` interface on your struct so that `Contains` calls the `Equals(IntVector2 other)` overload directly without having to box and unbox the value.

Answer (score -1):

With your current code, Contains is unable to determine equality for two structure instances.   If you override IntVector2::GetHashCode so that identical values return the same hash, it should start working as you expect.

Comment: `List` does not use `GetHashCode`.

Comment: List may not,  but Object.Equals does,  and List::Contain uses Object.Equals unless an alternative comparer is provided.

Comment: That is incorrect, unfortunately. You can put a breakpoint on `Equals` if you are not convinced. The default `Object.Equals` uses `Object.ReferenceEquals`